# Images Lost during PDF to EPUB conversion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image

I am making one Application which contains e-books in ePUB format..Problem is my original file is in PDF and when i try to convert it to ePUB format all Images are lost..Can anyone tell me how to convert PDF(Or any other format file)to ePUB without losing Images??Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give details as how you are creating the epub file.

Read the apple's guidelines for creating epub files [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4168)

It has been mentioned that "images beyond the 11MB of un-encoded image data allocation per chapter". But you should atleast get to see some of your images.

Comment: I've got .DOC format files(Doc file for each chapter) from client and I've to convert it to .ePUB file to use it in my App as i have implemented ePUB reader to read epub files..

Comment: If you are creating your own epub reader, may be it has some faults displaying images. Just make sure if it is reading images. As far as converting .doc to epub, apple recommends using their "pages" application that is available in "iWork".

Comment: Ok..I am able to covert small Image but image of 25 KB,Dimension : 530 × 365 are not able to converted..have look at screen shot of app..Small image is preserved as it is but larger one gets lost..

Comment: Screenshot of an app:
http://img818.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20110709at113.png/

Comment: So using iWork will I get ePUB properly with Images ??

Comment: iWork lets you create epub files, which apple recommends to use. Download iWork. Open your .doc file in "pages". iWork is a package like Microsoft office. One of the application in iWork is "Pages". You open your .doc file in "Pages" and do the formatting and then there is an option "export to epub". It will create epub file for you.

Comment: As far as big and small images are concerned, there is restriction on number of images you can use per chapter. You can use maximum 11mb of un-encoded image data per chapter. If such is your case, you can try to divide your chapters. If you want to test, make a .doc file that only contains one such "big image". Make epub from it using "Pages" and see if it is getting displayed. Display it in "your epub reader" and in "apple's iBook application". This would also make sure if your epub reader is faulty.

Comment: K..thanks...I'll try to convert Doc from iWork..

Comment: Well..My code is correct I downloaded another e-book with images and it works perfect...So i just need a convertor now..Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You need to Use i-Work 09 to successfully convert .doc file into .epub file that;s the only way to convert files..